# Simple problem with adding numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to input "2 3" aiming to get a result of 5 but this doesn't work and I'm not really sure why.

```
a = input()
b = (a[0])
c = (a[2])

print (int(b)) + (int(c))
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: try `print (int(b) + int(c))` instead

Answer (score 2):

In python3, `print()` is a *function*.  You have to use it like: `print(val)`.  python2 used to use `print val`, but python3 does not do this.

You need to do: `print(int(b) + int(c))`

---

In your code, you did: `print (int(b)) + (int(c))`.  You are doing `print(val) + val`, and `print()` doesn't return anything hence `NoneType` + `int`.